# how do I pull the larger photo when I pull my friends from graph?

Tags: facebook, graph

I'm pulling friends info and passing in `picture`, but that gets me the tiny square thumbnail.  Their docs seem to suggest that there's a way to get an array of images that include a larger version of this image, but I'm not succeeding in passing in any other param to get those urls.  Can someone let me know how to get a user's larger profile image?

```
FB.api( "/me/friends", 
    {"fields" : "name,birthday,picture,id"},
    function( response ){
    console.log("GOT RESPONSE.." + JSON.stringify(response));
    if(typeof response.data != "undefined")
                    drawFriends(response.data)
    }
);
```

Comment: You can specify the size of the pic when using the graph api - 
graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture?type=large. More info here under Pictures section - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: @deesarus, thanks... unfortunately that's a per-user call. I was hoping to pull the full list of friends (just as I'm doing) but have it include the larger image url

Comment: Using the Graph Explorer Field Expansion feature, I was able to confirm this works - me?fields=friends.fields(picture.type(large))

Comment: interesting... well... I'd paste that as an answer, cause that seems like the right one. However, could you point me to the documentation where you found this please?

Comment: The documentation for field expansion is available here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/, but to be honest, your best bet is to use the Graph Explorer and construct your own queries - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Graph Explorer Field Expansion feature, I was able to confirm this works - me?fields=friends.fields(picture.type(large))